# Modal segue needs 2 clicks instead of one

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

My UITableView needs 2 clicks to show the detail page of the selected cell : one for selection and another one for show the detail view. I would like one clic to directly show the detail view of the clicked cell.

I use a modal segue with this method inside my UITableViewManager.m :

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [playerList indexPathForSelectedRow];
        TCPlayerStat *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setPlayerStat:object];
    }
}
```

I can't work with a push segue because I don't have Navigation Controller (and don't really want to).

I've looked in the TableView Attribute Inspector but didnt find out anything relevant for this. I have Selection "Single Selection" selected and "Show Selection on Touch" checked.
I don't know if this is possible and if it is, where to look..

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT 1: When I write the two methods like this, it still doesn't work (needs 2 clicks) and I have a new warning log:

> "Warning: Attempt to present TCDetailViewController: 0xa27b900 on
>   TCRootViewController: 0xa24f050 while a presentation is in progress!"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [playerList indexPathForSelectedRow];
        TCPlayerStat *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        TCDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [detailViewController setPlayerStat:object];
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2: I don't know why, but sometimes it works perfectly and doesn't need a second click on the table view. Can't find out :/

---

**Solution below**

Comment: try, did select row at index path - then from there segue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fond out what the problem was!

I changed a parameter on the Storyboard that I shouldn't have. I wanted the selection cell not to display a background highlight color when I click on it, but it seems the Segue is based on it to work decently.

**HOW TO FIX:
In the storyboard, select your Table View Cell in the Navigator and don't chose the "None" option in "Selection" (Attributes Inspector). "Blue", "Gray" or "Default" seems to work nice.**

Answer (score 15):

I already had the selection attribute set to "Default" and was still experiencing the two-click problem. That suggestion did, however, point to a related solution. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, call:

```
self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
```

(I'm using Swift, obviously.)

Comment: This seems to be a strange bug that only affects Present Modally -> Cross Dissolve and Flip Horizontal. Your solution works perfectly Thanks

Comment: this changed to ```self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)```

Comment: Yes! This is the solution. You must deselect row you did select. And Selection option in Storyboard doesn't affect this. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom for me it appears even without segue at all, like:
`let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeController") as! SomeController`
 
`present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the more correct way to solve this problem is to perform any action on Main thread, in your case triggering the segue:

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
});
```

**Swift**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
}
```

It's actually a bug, related to the main RunLoop and tableViewCell, while selectionStyles force RunLoop to be awake (as it has to process the animation), if you don't have selectionStyle, plus you don't do any startup animations inside your presented viewController, RunLoop will go asleep sometimes.

If you, for some reason, don't want to do the action (in your case it's triggering the segue) on main thread, or you don't have startup animation on presented ViewController, you can simply add empty main thread call at the end and it will also trigger RunLoop to be awake.

**Objective-C**

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});
```

**Swift**

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
DispatchQueue.main.async {}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works for me (XCode 9.2) and seems easy, but still allows for `None` for the Selection is :

As @Tulleb says, in the storyboard use anything but `None` for the `Table View Cell` "Selection", but then set it to `.none` in the code.

For example, like this...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none  // This is the important line
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

instead of

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Then you can write any code and it works on the first click.

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere else. In the storyboard maybe. Can't find out...

My segue is already performed once by the Storyboard but it needs 2 clicks instead of one (on my table view) 75% of the time.
Sometimes it works very fine :/

Answer (score 0):

FYI. until now, with Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.x, the issue also exists for my customized `UICollectionViewCell` subclass (But I suppose subclass is not needed to reproduce this issue. I have no time to test this case.).

I summarize the issue as: **tapping on the previously selected cell will consume the tap event to cause deselection, instead of expectedly triggering the selection segues.**

So the solution is to, either not use the selection segues, say, but use programmatically triggering segues, or deselect the cell itself whenever a selection segue is triggered.