# UITableView Selection Segue needs two clicks to trigger

Tags: ios, objective-c

Related: [Modal segue needs 2 clicks instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483441/modal-segue-needs-2-clicks-instead-of-one)

In my table view, you often have to click the cell area multiple times for the segue to be triggered. The proposed answer in the above questions suggests not setting selection style, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Why is this happening, and how can I debug the problem?

Comment: Can you please show your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @Abhinav I didn't have to implement it, but I have `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Why not? How is your segue is being actioned otherwise? Could you please implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self];` from in there.

Comment: I created a segue from a tableViewController's prototype cell to another UIViewController. The segue is activated based on a selection of the cell. I could implement `didSelectRowAt..` but I thought it'd be redundant? Did I miss something?

Comment: What are the subviews in your cell? Is there anything added like a text field which could possibly stop touches from going through?

Comment: @Rege added a screenshot of the prototype cell. It seems to work better if I click on elements instead of on blank space in the cell. But the behavior is  inconsistent.

Comment: Everything look good. Something is going inside storyboard connections. Can you please remove the segue in storyboard, Ctrl+Drag from the UITableViewCell to our new view controller and then select the “show” segue in the “Selection Segue” section.

Comment: I doubt if you had used Accessory Action part of the connection overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my UITextViews had "user interaction enabled" setting turned on. When I clicked the blank part of the UITextView, the segue wasn't getting triggered.